# audio player not playing music

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, avfoundation

I tried to use the following piece of code to play audio, I debugged and found the soundURL is valid, the print statement printed some memory address of the object which indicates the object is instantiated, but there's still no sound, any ideas? thanks.

```
func kkTableView(tableView: UITableView, selectIndex indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let audioPlayer = generateAudioPlayerWithName(tickSounds![indexPath.row])
    print("\(audioPlayer)")
    audioPlayer.play()
}

func generateAudioPlayerWithName(name: String) -> AVAudioPlayer {
    let soundURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource(name, ofType: "wav")!)
    var audioPlayer: AVAudioPlayer
    do {
        try audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: soundURL)
        audioPlayer.numberOfLoops = -1
        return audioPlayer
    } catch {
        fatalError("\(error)")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see where you declared `name` which you use for the file name but I will assume you gave it a valid `String` leading to an existing file. The following code example will succesfully play audio with `AVAudioPlayer`, you can adapt this to your needs...

```
    var AudioURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Besides", ofType: "mp3")!)
    var AudioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()

   override func viewDidLoad() {
   super.viewDidLoad()

   do {
    try AudioPlayer  = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: AudioURL, fileTypeHint: nil)
   } catch {
    print("errorin do-try-catch")
   }

}

 @IBAction func(){
    AudioPlayer.play()
}
```

You need to keep a strong reference to AVAudioPlayer. Once it leaves its method it is deallocated

Answer (score 1):

Initialize `audioPlayer` globally , then instantiate it for using sound play. For more information please check https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vcs0BuDw9BA for playing audio.